# Where does Google Now get its weather data?

Tags: google-now, weather

What source/data provider does Google use for its weather data for Google Now (and other services)?

I've checked its forecasts against weather.gov, weather.com, accuweather.com, wunderground.com, and weatherstreet.com and can't find one that matches for the same location. The reason I ask is because there have been multiple times that it's forecast is horribly wrong. Case in point: currently its forecast is 13 degrees F lower than the closest one of the others above.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Google displays Weather conditions using Weather Underground as per [Google Web Search Features](http://www.google.com/intl/en/help/features_list.html#weather) page.

> All weather conditions and forecasts are provided by [Weather Underground, Inc](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.wunderground.com/&usg=__e__TBg5jW-bBbEG5WdETg3uO79M=).

So, Google Now also might be picking from the same source.

Comment: Thanks a lot for finding the official answer, and yes, I've seen the Google Now forecasts match the ones on google.com, so it's the same source. That said, I've still had multiple time where I've checked those forecasts against wunderground.com for the exact same location and found wildly different forecasts, so I'm not sure what that issue stems from.

Comment: I would think that Google caches the results, so it may be off by a bit as WU may update sooner.  Also, WU may update its own site faster than it updates its API.

Comment: As pointed out on [another answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/189144/71386) this one is obsolete.

Answer (score 5):

Though this question is almost 5 years old but I think an updated answer can help users looking for updated info. Nowadays Google gets its weather data from [weather.com](https://weather.com) as mentioned in bottom left corner of Google weather search results when you look for temperature of any location (highlighted in red rectangle). [image]

But as the OP says **a lot** of times Google's weather data is way off the actual current weather. For example as of this writing it shows current temperature in Shimla, India to be -4 C at 9 pm, [image] but according to official website of [Indian weather department or IMD](http://city.imd.gov.in/citywx/city_weather.php?id=42083) even whole day's minimum temperature was 1.4 C for 6 Jan 2018 and minimum temperature of whole day usually happens in early morning hours. [image] Similarly I have matched data for other cities and locations in India and current weather is not what actual current weather is. I think from wherever Google takes its weather data they just provide an average of previous years and not the actual current temperature. And various weather websites showing wildly different current temperatures for same location.

Comment: weather.com does not seem to have any way of getting hourly weather for the next 10 days. Is there an API that gets more weather forecast details than visible on the website?

Answer (score 1):

The Google search engine gets its weather from a combination of 'The Weather Channel', 'Weather Underground' and 'AccuWeather'.

The data on Google Now appears to be the same data...